# How to replace `\"` with `\\"` in R with other special characters

Tags: r, regex

I hope this is a simple answer, but there are so many threads on gsub and str_replace for working with backslashes. Ultimately I want to replace `\"` with `\\"`, but there are other special characters in there too like `\n`.

```
my_string <- "hello \"how are you?\nThat's great!"
desired_string <- "hello \\"how are you?\nThat's Great!"
```

Comment: It's not really clear what you mean here. In your example above, you don't have the character sequence `\"` . You simply have the character `"` which you have to type with a backslash to show R that you don't wish to terminate the string.. This is complicated by the fact that R will also print it with an escape backslash, but you need to remember it isn't really there. If you want a single literal backslash you have to type \\. So to get the literal character sequence `\\"` inside a character string (so it would appear that way in `cat`) you would do `\\\\\"`.

Comment: But you can't get the sequence `\\"` to appear inside a quoted character string - that's just an illegal sequence of characters. Your second example shows why. The R parser thinks you want a single backslash then a quote to close the string.

Comment: Try for example `cat("\\\\\"")`

Comment: Because of the reasons Allan mentioned, see that your `desired_string` isn't valid R syntax. If you attempt to run that line of code you get an error, because `\\ ` is interpreted as a single (escaped) backslash, so the second `"` ends the string, and the rest of the line of code is a syntax error...

Comment: Thanks both! I was starting to suspect this was the case but thanks for verifying!